# C++: getting the row size of a multidimensional array passed to a function

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, sizeof

I'm trying to write a function that will print out the contents of a multidimensional array. I know the size of the columns, but not the size of the rows.

EDIT: Since I didn't make this clear, the arrays passed to this function are NOT dynamically allocated. The sizes are known at compile time.

I am testing it using a 3x2 array. Here is the function as it stands:

```
void printArrays(int array1[][2], int array2[][2]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cout << "\narray1[" << i << "][" << j << "] = "
                 << setfill('0') << setw(2) << array1[i][j]
                 << "\tarray2[" << i << "][" << j << "] = "
                 << setfill('0') << setw(2) << array2[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this only works if I know the size of "i" is 3 (it is in this case). Ideally, however, I would like the function to work no matter what the size of the first dimension.

I thought I would be able to do this using the sizeof() function, e.g.

```
int size = sizeof(array1);
```

... and do some math from there.

Here's the odd part. If I use the sizeof() function inside the array, it returns a value of 4. I can use pointer notation to dereference the array:

```
int size = sizeof(*array1);
```

... but this actually returns a value of 8. This is odd, because the total size should be rows(which = 3) * columns(= 2) * sizeof(int)(= 4), or 24. And, indeed, this is the result, when I use sizeof(*array1) *outside* of the function.

Does anyone know what is going on here? More importantly, does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is that you can not do this. You must pass the number of rows as an argument to the function, or use an STL container such as `std::vector` or `std::array`.

`sizeof` is computed compile time; `sizeof` is never useful in determining dynamic size of objects in C/C++. You (yourself, the programmer) can always calculate `sizeof(x)` just from looking at code and header files since `sizeof` counts the number of bytes used to represent the object. `sizeof(*array1)` will always be 8 since `array1[i]` is an array of two `ints` and `4==sizeof(int)`. When you declare `int array1[][2]` this is equivalent to `int *array1[2]`. That is, `array1` is a pointer to arrays of two integers. `sizeof(array1)` is therefore 4 bytes, since it takes 4 bytes on your machine to represent a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd love to use vectors, but unfortunately, anything from the STL is not an option in this particular case (not my decision). So I guess I'll have to pass the row value to the function directly. Also, it's good to know how sizeof(*array1) works; I had assumed that it would return the total memory allocated for array1, not the memory allocated for array1[i].

Comment: Be careful when you say "memory allocated." sizeof does not know anything about dynamic memory allocation on the heap, only stack and global object allocation which is static. The type of `*array1` is an integer array with exactly two elements. `array1[i]` is equivalent to `*(array1+i)`.

Comment: Apologies. I should have made it clear in the original post, but the array size is NOT dynamically allocated. The function is simply required to handle arrays of different sizes, though these sizes are determined at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this, to some degree, by using templated functions.  The caveats are:

- You will need to include the function definition (not just declaration) anywhere it is used
- It will only work when array size is fixed at compile time
- You will generate a separate function for every call to the function, resulting in some code bloat

I am [working form the code on this blog post](http://heifner.blogspot.com/2008/04/c-array-size-determination-part-2.html) by Kevin Heifner.

```
template <typename T>
struct array_info
{
};

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
struct array_info<T[N][M]>
{
  typedef T type;
  enum { size1 = N, size2 = M };
};

template <typename A1>
void printArrays(A1 array1, A1 array2) {
    size_t A1_i = array_info<A1>::size1;
    size_t A1_j = array_info<A1>::size2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A1_i; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < A1_j; j++) {
            cout << "\narray1[" << i << "][" << j << "] = "
                 << setfill('0') << setw(2) << array1[i][j]
                 << "\tarray2[" << i << "][" << j << "] = "
                 << setfill('0') << setw(2) << array2[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a good answer. Unfortunately, I don't have the knowledge to understand it yet. :) Thank you, though, and I'll definitely bookmark the Heifner blog.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the size of both arrays with some template magic:

```
template< typename T, std::size_t n, std::size_t m >
void foo( T(&)[n][m] ) {
  std::cout << n << " " << m << std::endl;
}     

int main() {
  int a[3][3];
  int b[2][5];

  foo(a); foo(b);
}
```

This only works for arrays whose bounds are known at compile time and not for dynamically allocated arrays.

In any case: You should use `std::vector` or `boost::multiarray`.

Comment: *"This only works for arrays whose bounds are known at compile time and not for dynamically allocated arrays."* - In other words, it won't work for the OP and doesn't answer the question.  You don't need templates at all if the size is known at compile time...

Comment: Woah, there, Ed, little harsh.  We don't know if the bounds are entirely unknown.  It's possible this is a library function OP is building and the appropriate templates can be included in a header file.  Let's let OP comment on the appropriateness of the answer for his particular purpose.  If nothing else, informative answers may be helpful for other readers.

Comment: @Ed: In fact, the array size would be known at compile time (in this case); it is meant to be a function that can print out differently sized (but known) arrays.

Comment: @Karl My spidey senses told me this.

Answer (score 2):

The size is 8 outside the function because you're dereferencing the first array, which gives you the column size (2) times the size of an `int` (4). If you wanted 24, you'd do `sizeof(array)` (outside the function). The answer is 4 *inside* the function because it treats `array` like a pointer, the size of which is 4 bytes.

However, to reliably get the size of arrays that have been passed to functions, you either have to pass the size or use something like `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do it, without needing vectors, templates, classes, or passing the size of the array, is to have a last row of data that contains something unique such as the following example, where a -1 is used in the last row, first column:

```
#define DATA_WIDTH 7

const float block10g[][DATA_WIDTH] = {
  {0, 15, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125},
  {2.12, 0, 1.000269, 3.000807, 4.24114056, 5.28142032, 6.001614},
  {6.36, 0, 1.2003228, 3.84103296, 6.24167856, 8.16219504, 10.08271152},
  {10.6, 0, 1.2003228, 4.4011836, 7.2019368, 9.2024748, 11.8031742},
  {21.2, 0, 2.000538, 6.001614, 8.002152, 10.4027976, 14.4038736},
  { -1}
};


const float block10g[][DATA_WIDTH] = {
  {0, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250},
  {2.12, 0, 2.88077472, 5.04135576, 5.84157096, 6.08163552, 5.84157096},
  {6.36, 0, 3.84103296, 7.92213048, 11.52309888, 13.56364764, 14.4038736},
  {10.6, 0, 3.8010222, 8.8023672, 13.003497, 16.4044116, 18.4049496},
  {21.2, 0, 4.4011836, 9.2024748, 14.003766, 18.4049496, 22.4060256},
  { -1}
};

printArrays(block10g,block20g);
```

Then just break out of the loop(s) when you reach that unique value:

```
void printArrays(float array1[][DATA_WIDTH], float array2[][DATA_WIDTH]) {

    for (int i = 0; array1[i][0]!=-1 && array2[i][0]!=-1 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DATA_WIDTH; j++) {

            cout << "\narray1[" << i << "][" << j << "] = "
                 << array1[i][j]
                 << "\tarray2[" << i << "][" << j << "] = "
                  << array2[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use better arrays!

What I mean by that is you can make your own array class which wraps an array, or use some common libraries with such classes (e.g. boost). This is much more reliable, and likely is easier to reason about that straight-up C++ arrays.

One reason for this is if your write the function

```
void foo( int a[][2] )
{
    // etc.
}
```

you don't actually have as many guarantees on the array as you might think. For example, it is *not* guaranteed that the second dimension of the array is two elements wide (I could be wrong about this point, as I don't have references on hand, but I'm pretty confident about it). This is because that actual signature for the function is

```
void foo( int ** );
```

This is because arrays degenerate to pointers when used in function declarations (which is why you're `sizeof(array)` returns 4, since 4 bytes is the size of a pointer type on your machine). Also, you *clearly* have no guarantee on the size of the first dimension, so assuming it is going to be 3 is dangerous, and potentially the result of confusing bugs in the future.

This is where a custom `array` class would be great, especially if it were templated. For example, a two dimensional array class could be declared like

```
template<typename T, int length1, int length2>
class Array2D
{
    // Array2D's gutsy stuff to make it act kind of like T[length1][length2]
};
```

Using such an approach allows you to maintain *all* the information about the array in *any* situation, e.g.

```
void foo( Array2D<int, 3, 2> &array ) {}
```

Now you can decide the sizes every dimension in the array.

An added benefit, is that you can add bounds checking to your `Array2D` class, which C++ array do not have. E.g. in a 3x2 array, you are able to access the fourth element in the first row, even though it's not conceptually valid. Such a common source of bugs can easily be eradicated by using an array class like Array2D.

There are some drawbacks, which is normal when using templates. The big one is that, because of the way template are instantiated, you have to define any templated classes in your header files, not in separate source files (technically, you can use the "export" keyword to do split the class up as normal, but this has limited support on major compilers).

As a last note (if you're interested, as I am), the situation becomes even better in C++0x (comming soon!) with the advent of variadic templates:

```
template<typenameT, int... lengths>
class Array
{
    // etc...
};
```

Now all array types can be defined by a single class template. Never been easier.