# Initializing C++ arrays with pointers, getting size 8

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, sizeof

I am trying to create a two-dimensional array in C++ using the double pointer method. But when I initialize the variable I always get that the array is size 8. At first I tried this:

```
  double** sobel_x;
```

And got the size to be 8, and then when I tried this:

```
  double** sobel_x;
  sobel_x = new int*[3];
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(sobel_x); i++) {
    sobel_x[i] = new int[3];
  }
```

Can someone explain to me first why the array is initialized to size 8 and second how to change that size?

Comment: `new int` --> `new double` ?

Comment: How do you check the size? You probably see the size of the pointer, not the size of the array - which you threw away by storing only a pointer.

Comment: @P0W thanks! I didn't even notice that I did that

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
double** sobel_x = new int*[3];
std::cout << sizeof(sobel_x);
```

will always print the `sizeof` ***pointer*** because `sizeof` is evaluated in compile time (based on the type, which is `double**` in this case), regardless what you have assigned to this pointer in runtime.

Use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > sobel_x(3, std::vector<double>(3, 0.0));
std::cout << sobel_x.size();
```

---

Note that even if you would be able to retrieve the size, the size would be in ***bytes***. It wouldn't give you the count of elements. To achieve this with arrays, you could use a static array with automatic storage duration:

```
double sobel_x[3][3] = { 0.0 };
std::cout << sizeof(sobel_x);                         // <-- outputs 72
std::cout << sizeof(sobel_x[0]);                      // <-- outputs 24
std::cout << sizeof(sobel_x) / sizeof(sobel_x[0]);    // <-- outputs 3
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with arrays?

Comment: hmm okay, I guess this brings me to my second problem then, I am trying to use this array in another function I wrote that I designed to take an arbitrary array size as input. And I've found in C++ that you can't declare a function `void FunctionName(double[][] array)` you have to use `void FunctionName(double** array)`. So is there any way to make an array that will work in `FunctionName`?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling sizeof on sobel_x, and sobel_x is a pointer. This means 8 is the sizeof a pointer on your system (presumably a 64bit machine).

This post explains that you can't do what you want to do:[C++: getting the row size of a multidimensional array passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934776/c-getting-the-row-size-of-a-multidimensional-array-passed-to-a-function)

If you need to calculate the length at runtime, use one of the STL classes like vector.

Though for your simple use case, you already know how many elements are in the array pointed to by sobel_x (3 in this case), so just use that as the test condition in your loop.