# Size of a 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am solving problems on online judge like Leetcode and I wonder if it' possible to get size of a 2d array given int**A. Consider the function,

```
 int help(int** A){
       int rows = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
       int columns = sizeof(A[0])/sizeof(A[0][0]);
}
```

But I am not getting the correct values of rows and columns.
Is there a way to get sizes of a 2d array if I only have int** A. Same question for char** A.
I know that the question is poorly framed but I am a beginner in C. Thank you.

Comment: This is not possible in C.  Do you want C or C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find 2d array size in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274162/how-to-find-2d-array-size-in-c)

Comment: Possible in C++?

Comment: For C++ see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934776/c-getting-the-row-size-of-a-multidimensional-array-passed-to-a-function

Comment: [A better way to handle a 2D rectangular array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Comment: [Finding length of array inside a function (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17590226/995714), [How to get array size within function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39429730/995714), [Using sizeof() on an array passed to a function (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27096272/995714)

Answer (score 1):

#### No, this is not possible.

There's nothing in the allocated memory that indicates where it starts and ends. For 2D arrays, there's not even a guarantee the memory is contiguous.

`**A` does not contain any data about itself - all of the info about the array must be kept track of by the programmer.

Comment: Actually `**A` isn't a pointer to the first element in an array. It's a pointer to another pointer that points to an int. There may or may not be ints following. It might also be a pointer to an array of pointers and the first element of that array points to an int. But that's all speculation. The only thing known for sure is that it's a pointer to a pointer to an int.

Comment: `**A` is not "the address of a pointer to a pointer of an int".   `**A` is actually an `int`.   `*A` is a pointer to an `int`, and its value is the address of an `int`.   `A` is a pointer to a pointer to an int - so its value may be the address of a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: @Peter I should have  referred to the declaration `int **A` which declares a pointer to a pointer to an int. You are, of course, correct that the stand alone expression `**A` is just an int. But I think the context is clear given that `**A` only appears in a declaration.

Comment: @doug - I was not responding to your comment.   I responded to content of the answer at that time - which said that `**A` was "the address of a pointer to a pointer of an int".   It has since been edited to remove that text.